# read properties from custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have an `Aspect` with an annotation like this

```
@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LoggerExecute {
    public String action(); 
}
```

So I can put the annotation on the functions that I want to log. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(....)
@LoggerExecute(action = "Logging submitting data")
public ModelAndView submitData(...) {
    ....
}
```

Now I have a `eventLogs.properties` which contains all the texts for the action, located in the resources folder. What is the easy way to read that keys in the `.properties` file right from the `LoggerExecute` Annotation. Injecting a Environment variable or overriding some classes seems too much for this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An annotation attribute value must be a constant expression. Therefore, you can't do something like

```
@LoggerExecute(action = loadFromProperties(someKey))
```

What you can do is create and use a `String` key value in the annotation

```
@LoggerExecute(action = "myapp.action.submit.data")
```

Then, in your advice, retrieve the annotation, look up the `action` value in your properties file, and use it.